# Input binding for ListBox items

Tags: wpf, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` with `ItemsSource` bound to a list in the view-model. 
I want to bind a command to a double-click event on each item with the item as a parameter.

example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

If I simply attach a command to the `ListBox`, I wouldn't be able to send the `Item` clicked as a parameter.

Example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<ListBox.InputBinding>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="MyCommand" CommandParameter="{ ?? No way to send the right item ?? }"/>
</ListBox.InputBinding>
```

I also try to bind it to a container in an ItemTemplate like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                        </Grid.InputBindings>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And it worked but than the command was only invoked if you clicked **inside** the container. Mark here as yellow:

[image]

I want the command to be invoked if I click anywhere inside the item. (The area marked in blue when selecting the item).

I found some similar questions but none of them has a answer that does what I want.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
       <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
</Style>
```

By default the ContentPresenter inside ListBoxItem has HorizontalAlignment="Left" and VerticalAlignment="Center".You can see the Template of ListBoxItem below

```
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#1F26A0DA" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A826A0DA" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#3DDADADA" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFDADADA" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#3D26A0DA" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF26A0DA" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Acceptable solution, but I wonder if there is a way to bind the inputs directly to the items and not having to overwrite the default `ListBoxItem` template. (as shown in my first example)

Comment: You don't need to override the defaul template.just add the style at top of my answer

Comment: Sorry,I'm a bit confused

Comment: The original question was "how to bind an input for a listboxitem". You said "you don't need to override the default template, just add the style at the top of my answer". Your style does nothing related to bind an input. Only combined with the last solution proposed in the question (which require overriding the template) it can do what I want. Only I think it's not at neat as it could. (for example - a syntax for adding an `InputBinding` to each `ListBoxItem` in my list box could be really nice.

Comment: "Did you try to pass SelectedItem to CommandParameter" - this is not my problem.